# Arrange in ascending order based on one parameter and remove any objects after first 6 from array Angular 8

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting a complex json response and I am getting 15 objects in an array. I want to keep only 6 out of 15 which have the lowest value of parameter `amount`. Object structure is as below:

```
obj{
   array[
        obj1{
             name = 'abc';
             amount = '100';
            },
        obj2{
             name = 'xyz';
             amount = '200';
            }
        ]
  }
```

In reality I have 15 objects. Now I want to rearrange them in ascending order based on `amount` and only keep the first 6. Then I am trying to find the lowest one and store it in a separate array. Ex. if `abc` has lowest `amount` out of the 6 objects. I will store that in separate array and rest 5 in separate array. If 2 or more have same lowest `amount` I want to add all those to one array and remaining others to the other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to sort the array and then take from it any number of objects you like.

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.amount- b.amount; //to reverse b.amount-a.amount
});
array2 = array.splice(1,6);
```

Comment: can you please explain a little more. I mean what is a.amount and b.amount?  I am not finding the difference in the values and then arranging. If obj1.amount <obj2.amount. I want obj1 to be pushed into separate array else obj2. Can you shed some light on how to push those separately.

Comment: First you want to get 6 lowest values from the group of 15. So you're sorting it decs. then you take first 6, so now you only have 6 objects. Then just check is any elements in this array have same values if so push them all ( with the same values) if not push just the smallest one (should be arr[0]).

Comment: It is working fine @reznov46 Just one issues. Suppose out of the last 6 objects, if two or more have same lowest amount I want to compare on another parameter: value. Then the object with lowest value would be considered. If value is also same for more than two objects then need to push both into the arrayLowest and rest in arrayHigher

Comment: Sorry please ignore the previous comment. Suppose the lowest amount is only in one object, multiple objects, how can I move those objects into arrayLowest and remaining into arrayHigher?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question and make it a bit more clear? I'm guessing you're not natvie english speaker, so am I, it's a bit hard to understand what you want to do now.